# Changing namespace using vstemplate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating a custom project template in VS 2010, and I want to add prefix to all of these projects (it is a template for sub-projects within a solution).

So, if I create "NewProject" I want it to have the namespace "MasterSolution.NewProject".

I can manually alter the namespace within the .cs files, so if I had a Class1.cs then it says

```
    using MasterSolution.NewProject
```

but intellisense only picks up "NewProject", not "MasterSolution".

Is there an entry in the .vstemplate that can alter the namespace?

Thanks